# Replace value and convert type of a dataframe as a value in a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dict:

[image]

I need to exclude the "," sign that separates the numbers. So instead of 10,599.01, I need 10599.01 I also need to convert it to float.

I tried the following code, but did not work

assets["nikkei"] = assets["nikkei"].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)

How should I do it? The value of the dict is a pandas dataframes

Comment: Maybe : assets["nikkei"].price = assets["nikkei"].price.str.replace(',', '').astype(float)

Comment: I just realized that I have actually one column. So I need to split into two I guess

Comment: Can you run `print(assets.head(5).to_dict())` and include that in your question so that your data as is copyable so we can build your dataframe _exactly_ how it is?

Comment: apparently, dict has no .head()